# Mapview showing black zones

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

I made a `MapView` with geopoints map is loading with black squares as in picture any idea for the solution?

[image: MapView]

Answer (score 0):

I saw a similar thing when having this set:

`gMapView.setStreetView(true);`

Setting it to false removed those areas.

Comment: Not saying that can't potentially solve the problem, but that image in the question is no where near street view

Comment: tnx for reply but i dont have set the streetview or satellite